# pygame clock managed process accelerates and shouldn't

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm doing an RPG in pygame and just added portals to get from a map to another one. The problem is that when I get back to the first map, somehow movement and animation of my player character accelerate a lot. This acceleration is increased each time that I get back and forth.

Time is managed with a pygame clock object at 32 ticks per second:

```
time_passed = clock.tick(32)
self.worlds[self.currentWorld].process(time_passed)
```

general process method:

```
def process(self, time_passed):
    tps = time_passed/1000.0
    for entity in self.entities.itervalues():
        entity.process(tps)
```

process method for an entity:

```
def process(self, tps):
    if self.location != self.destination and self.animseq != None:
        self.tps += tps
        if self.tps > 0.25:
            self.tps -= 0.25
            self.image_to_render1 += 1
            if self.image_to_render1 > self.animn:
                self.image_to_render1 = 0
```

"teleport" method

```
def changeWorld(self, target):
    self.currentWorld = target
    self.worlds[self.currentWorld].addEntity(self.player)
    self.player.world = self.worlds[self.currentWorld]
    self.player.location.x = 200
    self.player.location.y = 200
    self.player.reset()
```

The reset is what I first tried to solve the problem, it resets the animations and player associated time, but it didn't change anything. I wonder if I just got something wrong with the clock or if I should recreate one on teleport. I hope someone can give me a clue, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you should use return value from Clock.tick if you pass in framerate. You are already throttling - just use a constant. Docs are not 100% conclusive, but it is entirely possible that it returns delay between start of this call and END of previous call, which will become larger with more load.

Comment: Search supports that hypothesis) http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=pygame.time.Clock.tick

Comment: Do you mean that I should just use 1/32 seconds (for example)  per frame instead of what the clock returns?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Apparently that's not it, when using a constant, I still get accelerated after coming back from the second map. Maybe it doesn't have to with the clock directly...

Comment: Oh, I see the problem) Will post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple logic error – you forget to remove your player from previous "world" when teleporting:

```
def changeWorld(self, target):
    self.currentWorld = target
    self.worlds[self.currentWorld].addEntity(self.player)
    # Where's deleteEntity on the old world?
```

so when he comes back, there's two of the same player in the `world.entities` list. And then it gets processed twice, and moves twice faster.

This kind of error would be very easy to catch using basic debugging - if you would just put logging in your loop and in `player.process` methods, you would clearly see something like this in the output:

```
starting tick
processing player
processing player    <--- There is two of them where should be only one!
starting tick
processing player
processing player
starting tick
processing player
processing player
```

Next time try to use debugging (it is harder in visual applications, but not impossible) or logging to make sure every entity in your state is exactly what you expect it to be at every step, and when you find discrepancy, it will be much easier to find a source of it. Good luck!

Comment: You're right. But that leads to another problem: I can't just take out entries of a dictionary, because it gives me a runtime error (...size changed during iteration) and so far I have no idea about how I could do it otherwise.

Comment: EDIT: And I got another problem: Somehow my player doesn't have the right id 
That's what I use to add an entity (I can't see what's wrong...):
    def addEntity(self, entity):
         self.entities[self.entity_id] = entity
         entity.id = self.entity_id
         self.entity_id += 1

Somehow the code doesn't work...

Comment: Just use a set instead of dict. No id, no duplicates. Or use `values()` instead of `itervalues()`. I'm sorry, this is not a tutoring site, it's a Q&A... You should accept the answer and try to work through your bugs yourself. Use debugging, see what your variables are at all times, look where it diverges from what you had in mind.

Comment: I got it to work, finally, even with a dict. Thanks for your instrctions!